# The splitting field of $x^{20}-1$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to find the splitting field of $x^{20}-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. I know that it has degree $8$ over $\mathbb Q$, and that $i$ and $\sqrt5$ are in the splitting field. I am also suspecting that $\sqrt[4]5$ is in the splitting field, which would mean that the splitting field is $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt[4]5)$, but am uncertain about how to prove this. Could anyone help me on those regards?

EDIT: After consideration, the splitting field is most likely $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$, but how does one show this without the exact trigonometric value?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field et https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_values I doubt $\sqrt[4]5$ is in the splitting field $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}).$

Comment: Thanks! I know that this is the splitting field, but how does one prove it without knowing the exact trigonometric value?

Comment: I edited the tags a bit. There are infinitely many elements in $\Bbb{Q}$ already, so [tag:finite-fields] was inappropriate. I would use [tag:field-theory] instead.

Comment: It can be proved that $\sqrt[4]5$ is not in the splitting field of $x^{20}-1$.

Comment: What @Apass.Jack said is correct. A simple way to see that is to observe that the Galois group of this splitting field is Abelian. Hence every subgroup of the Galois group is normal, implying that every intermediate field is a normal extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. but $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of5)$  is not normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be the splitting field of $x^{20}-1$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Let $i\not=\pm1$ be a root of $x^4-1=0$, i.e., $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Let $\alpha\not=1$ be a root of $x^5-1=0$.

Consider $i^j\alpha^k$, where $0\le j<4$ and $0\le k<5$.

- $(i^j\alpha^k)^{20}=(i^{20})^j(\alpha^{20})^k=1\cdot1=1.$
- Suppose $i^{j_1}\alpha^{k_1}=i^{j_2}\alpha^{k_2}$, where $0\le j_1,j_2<4$, $0\le k_1,k_2<5$. Then $i^{j_2-j_1}\alpha^{k_2-k_1}=1$.

  - $1=(i^{j_2-j_1}\alpha^{k_2-k_1})^4=\alpha^{4(k_2-k_1)}=\frac1{\alpha^{k_2-k_1}}$. Hence $k_2=k_1$.
  - $1=(i^{j_2-j_1}\alpha^{k_2-k_1})^5=i^{5(j_2-j_1)}=i^{j_2-j_1}$. Hence $j_2=j_1$.

Hence, all roots of $x^{20}-1$ are $i^j\alpha^k$. The splitting field is $Q(i,\alpha)$.

(More generally, the splitting field of $x^{ab}-1$ is the product field of the splitting field of $x^a-1$ and that of $x^b-1$ when $\gcd(a,b)=1$).

---

What are the roots of $x^5-1=0$?

Since $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^2+\frac{1+\sqrt5}2x+1)(x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt5}2x+1)$,
the roots are
$(1, \frac{-1- \sqrt 5\pm i\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt 5}}4, \frac{-1+ \sqrt 5\pm i\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt 5}}4).$

Consider root $\alpha = \frac{-1+ \sqrt 5+ i\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt 5}}4\not=1$.
We know $$S=\Bbb Q(i,\alpha),$$
which can be the sought solution.

---

$\frac1\alpha=\frac{-1+ \sqrt 5- i\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt 5}}4$.
$\sqrt 5=4(\alpha +\frac1\alpha)+\frac12$.
Hence $\sqrt5\in S$. So is $\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}=(4\alpha+1-\sqrt5)/i$. Hence, $\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})\subseteq S$.

One the other hand, since $\sqrt5=\frac{\left(\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}\right)^2-10}2$, we have $\alpha\in \Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$. Hence $S\subseteq \Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5})$.

So we know $$ S=\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}),$$ which can be the sought solution, too, as you suspected.

---

Similarly, we can obtain $$S=\Bbb Q(i, \beta)=\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{10-2\sqrt 5})$$ using $\beta=\frac{-1- \sqrt 5+ i\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt 5}}4$, another root of $x^5=1$.

It must be true that $\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt 5}\in Q(i, \sqrt{10+2\sqrt 5})$. Here is how we can see this containment directly. Note that $(10-2\sqrt5)(10+2\sqrt5)=80$, we have
$$\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}=\frac{4\sqrt5}{\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt 5}}\in Q(\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt 5}).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Take a primitive $20$th root of unity $\zeta$.  Its minimal polynomial is $\Phi_{20}$, the twentieth cyclotomic polynomial over $\Bbb Q.$  It's irreducible by a result of Gauss's.

Then you want $\Bbb Q(\zeta).$

Since $\cos(\pi /{10})=1/4(\sqrt{2\sqrt5 +10}),$ we should have $\Bbb Q(\zeta) =\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{2\sqrt5 +10}).$

Comment: The field $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{5})$ only has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but the field we are looking for has degree $8$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Oh yeah,  you're right.   @BrianShin